# How do I hide a control under another one?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I am trying to hide a control I have one my second Column definition but for some reason doing it using the ZIndex property just didnt work.

So what would be the most efficient way of hiding my StackPanel in Column 1 under the grid on Column 0

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Column="0">
            <Grid Background="Orange"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Column="1">
            <StackPanel Width="100"
                        Height="100"
                        Background="#212121" Margin="-102,158,266,161"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you post whole xaml file or at least parts with reproducible issue?

Comment: @DipenShah That is the entire XAML document. I clearly explained what I was trying to do. Hide the *StackPanel in Column 1 under the grid on Column 0*

Comment: My friend, you cannot move control over another one if they are in different Grid columns. Either set column's width 0 or use same column and use ZIndex to lay one control over another.

Comment: @DipenShah
Oh really?
https://i.imgur.com/8J2nrLB.png

Comment: Of course you could set a margin but AFAIK framework will clip content which is outside column bounds. But I'm really interested so see how you can use ZIndex in your use case!

Answer (score -1):

It works for here setting the ZIndex.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Column="0" Panel.ZIndex="2">
        <Grid Background="Orange"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Column="1" Panel.ZIndex="1">
        <StackPanel Width="100"
                    Height="100"
                    Background="#212121" Margin="-102,158,266,161"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

If only want to hide it you could set the `Visibility`.

```
<Grid Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

You can also control the ZIndex by changing the order of the Grids in the XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Column="1">
        <StackPanel Width="100"
                Height="100"
                Background="#212121" Margin="-102,158,266,161"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Column="0" Width="150">
        <Grid Background="Orange"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

As mentioned above if you really want to span to columns you should set the Grid.ColumnSpan `<Grid Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">`

Comment: Using XAML, I want to hide the *StackPanel in Column 1 under the grid on Column 0* I've tried using the ZIndex property as I explained. But that didnt work. I wouldnt be using WPF if I was going to do code behind.

Comment: @MarkDenom What is your point about code behind? The WPF and no-code-behind mantra: No logical code that belongs to the ViewModel or Model. But code you need for presentation (f.i. paint the canvas in red) does not belong to ViewModel or Model so it has to be on the View side. You may inject the code with an AttachedProperty (which is the way to go in most cases) but it is code on the View side.

Comment: @Mark Denom Can you explain exactly what isn't working? What results are you expecting to see? Also why the down vote. I never intended my answer to require code behind.